# template function binding lua

Tags: templates, lua, cocos2d-x

I'm using lua in cocos2dx.
There is a template function, like:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    template<class T1, class T2>
    static ClassA* createClassA(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}
```

how can I binding this function to lua?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to bind single static function `int createClassA(lua_State* L);` that will check actual Lua arguments types, and call specific template method. Means there has to be some kind of switch in native code, and all possible cases should be instantiated in the native host.

Comment: You mean there is no way to export templates implementations from cpp to lua?

Comment: Lua has no notion of function signature. It's just a single value. So you need either separate Lua functions for different template instantiations, or you must select exact instantiation by checking Lua arguments. In either way it's your responsibility (or your c++ binding library/framework), Lua can't help here.

Comment: thanks, "or you must select exact instantiation by checking Lua arguments" if lua arguments is a usertype, Is there any ...

Comment: Those user types must be created in the way that allows distinguish between types. It might be some type id field at the known offset within user type value, or some agreement on metatable names/ids or methods. If user type wasn't created by your code, you can't possibly know what was that type originally, so can't select exact template instance.

Comment: thanks, for a C++ template class, how can I binding Lua in cocos2dx 3.9? TOLUA_TEMPLATE_BIND in tolua++ can help? please help~

Comment: TOLUA_TEMPLATE_BIND creates multiple versions of same class, each having unique name on Lua side. It won't help binding templated methods withing same class.

Comment: @Vlad but templates exist only before compilation. At compilation they are compiled to many version (each version corresponding to a used type). And the binding code (to Lua) has to be compiled too. so if it compiles *after* the templates,  why can't the compiler know what types there are going to be?

Comment: @I-V, binding code is implemented with templates, so generated/compiled at the same time as hosting app. Anyway, issue is not in native side. Lua doesn't care about argument types, because arguments don't have types, only actual values binded to arguments variables has it. So Lua can't select exact native function by itself, it needs someone to do that job. tolua++ generates multiple bindings, yet on Lua side you must explicitly call different functions. And even tolua++ can't bind templated functions at the moment.